# Dumbbell Workout for Fitness not Muscle Gain

Tags: muscle-gain

Due to changes in my work situation, my gym membership cost is going to increase significantly. To save the monthly cost, I was considering getting some dumbbells and doing workouts at home three or four times a week.

At the moment, I go the gym three or four times a week, doing mainly cardio (rowing machine and cross trainer) and a bit of free weights (3 sets of 10 reps). This is because I'm not after muscle gain, I'm just trying to keep fit.

Is it sensible/possible to have a keep fit work out with dumbbells? I've seen people claiming that their regime is a full body work out, but is that enough to keep me fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - Definitely.

If your aim is to only "keep fit" and not muscle gain. This is simply achieved. Raise your heart rate often and frequently. Repeat.

You have successfully gained fitness. Having dumbells will greatly increase your muscle usage and therefore increase the amount of energy you are exerting which will in time help you sweat more and push your body further helping you to stay fit.